# Can I extract Flash SWF sprite frames to bitmaps?

Tags: c#, unity, flash, swf

I want to create the 2D graphics of my game in Flash Studio, but then get all the frames from my SWF movies into C# for further work in Unity3D.

I find it easier to create nice smooth animations in Flash Studio. But then I also want the performance Unity gives and the multi-platform support as well.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [ShoeBox](http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/) it has many utilities for SWF files.
One of those allows you to create spritesheets from a SWF file.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you're looking for, [this post on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/29k4io/sneak_peak_of_new_unity3dwebglstage3d_library_for/) might be of interest - an upcoming tool for rendering swf animations in Unity, from the sounds of it the performance is good and you still retain the cross-platform functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using Flump: http://threerings.github.io/flump/

You'll have to port one of the existing client libraries to Unity, but the client libs are simple and should be pretty easy to port. Most of the heavy lifting is done by the exporter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean "Flash Pro". You can export a sprite sheet directly from inside Flash Pro. Instructions are available on Adobe's web site.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/create-sprite-sheet.html

This will take a snapshot of each frame of the animation, at the interval for the frame rate you specify, then combine all the frames into a grid in a single image.

You can then load the sprite sheet into Unity to create the animation. There's a tutorial on raywenderlich.com showing how to do this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/61532/unity-2d-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools for this purpose. Flash itself has an option for something like Export to PNG Sequence. [Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) also can import a SWF. Yet another option, which I used to create the spritesheets for [the HTML5 demo](http://www.newarteest.com/easel-demo/easel-demo.html) on my site, is [Zoe](http://www.createjs.com/#!/Zoe), the spritesheet tool that comes with CreateJS.